# jQuery href attr doesn't update on .click() event

Tags: jquery, href, attr

I am learning the basics on jQuery and feel this should work based on what I've learned so far. Why doesn't the href get updated with the button click event?

Thanks

(The jQuery .js is loaded in the header correctly)

```
<div>
<input id = "ChangeLink" type="submit" value="Change Link"/>
</div>

<div class="divClass">
<ul id="defaultList">
    <li><a id="link1" href="#">Item 0</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#changeLink").click(function() {
        $("#link1").attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should probably be using `.prop()` rather than `.attr()`

Answer (score 4):

Your jQuery selector says `#changeLink` but your the id of your element is `ChangeLink` (with a capital). Make them both the same.

Comment: (If you select an answer then your question won't still show as unsolved to other users)

Answer (score 3):

You have wrong id, is `$("#ChangeLink").click(function()` with capital -C-:

```
$("#ChangeLink").click(function() {
        $("#link1").attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
        return false;
    });
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L06hL5nr/3/)